# How can dagger2 inject objects of the same class with different scopes?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, okhttp, dagger

There are 2 scopes in my application, which are 1) `Singleton` lives along with the application process and 2) `UserScope` starts immediately after the user log in and ends immediately before the user log out.

When user is not logged-in, there's a general `OkHttpClient` (from OkHttp3) for use which has no authentication, while during the `UserScope` all network must go through an authenticated `OkHttpClient`.

There are two solutions come to my mind by neither I think is best practice:

1): Using a `Singleton` OkHttpClient with a TokenInterceptor, which has a `setToken` method, use it everywhere and set different token values. This is currently what I'm using. The main problem here is that the `setToken` method and the getter must be synchronized to ensure thread safety.

2): Using `@Named` injection. This is worse. Say we name two types of OkHttpClient, `unauthorized` and `authorized`, the problem is that the `authorized` object is not always there as the user maybe not logged-in. 
So what's the best practice to work with this use case?

Background: In my project there's Dagger2, Retrofit2 and OkHttp3. And the server will send different sets of data when authorized and unauthorized.

Comment: The way I see it there's no issue with option 1. You have one dependency - the ``OkHttpClient`` and its interceptors change behaviour depending on the user session. Having a synchronised setter and getter is not an issue. The lack of synchronisation was a problem solved long time ago and nowadays shouldn't be seen as such. Synchronisation is actually a solution and a pretty good one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use UserScope for OkHttpClient instance, so I have single OkHttpClient while user is logged in. This OkHttpClient is instantiated once after user login, and I set token exactly once.
If user isn't logged I use another OkHttpClient with scope, related to my LoginActivity lifecycle.